# People or group column not working on datasheet view

Tags: 2007, datasheet

I am facing an issue related to a custom group mapped to a list column.

I have a custom list with a custom column "Responsible" of type "people or groups" with following settings,

- Allow multiple selections = No
- Allow selection of = People only
- Choose from = sharepoint group
- Show field = Name(with presence)

When I edit the item in the list, the "responsible" column shows all the available persons in the custom group "ResponsiblePersons".

When iIedit the same in "Edit in Datasheet" mode, "Responsible" dropdown column shows all the users/groups name at the site collection level. Is it the default behaviour of SharePoint 2007?

Could you please tell me how to restrict the dropdown values to only those available in the custom group "ResponsiblePersons"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, yes this is the default behavior.

We ran into the same issue some time ago and I believe we found that it was never going to be fixed in SharePoint 2007 but that it was fixed in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not fix in Sharepoint 2010 either. I just tested, and the field shows all the users and groups defined in site collections instead of picked SP group.
Any other inputs on this? Thanks,

Comment: Facing this same issue now. Any updates on this?

Comment: Facing the issue in 2007? If so, you're out of luck. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with Sharepoint 2010 and able to resolve the same by repairing my Microsoft Office 2010 installation.

Control Panel -> Microsoft Office 2010 -> Change -> Repair

After completion of repair I restarted the system and the issue was fixed on my system.