# Using Person field in Datasheet view with Claims/FBA

Tags: claims-based-auth, people-picker

Is it possible to use a person field in datasheet view when the site is configured to use Claims/FBA? It's currently not working, when I click the field I get the usual dropdown but it has a check box with (All), which doesn't do anything. I can't pick actual users from the site. I'm guessing this is a limitation of using a site with Claims.

Thanks

Comment: David: Did you ever find an answer. We have a product built on Sharepoint that uses claims based auth as well. Our issue is slightly different than yours. In Datasheet view it displays all groups, and users, includng users now removed from the site collection. I went into the native out of the box web application that only uses A/D, and it behaves exactly the same. But only in datasheet. If in standard, it works according to the specifications in the list column settings. I wrote about this in the technet forums to see if there might be someone that can explain this behavior and to help me pur

Comment: unfortunately no, didn't find a solution. I suggest posting a new question for your issue so it gets the proper attention

Comment: @Paul I think you are referencing the same issue as this question...? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/6010/2070